# Do I need JRE_HOME? Tomcat java environment version difference

Tags: java, environment-variables, tomcat9

Recently I had come across an error while running a basic webapp in tomcat. 
The error was "class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment". I am using jdk-11.0.2 and jre1.8.0_201. Then I came across [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) page about setting tomcat server which says :

`If both JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are specified, JRE_HOME is used`

So I tried deleting the JRE_HOME variable and that solved the error.
Is this the right method to solve the issue? Is it possible to make JRE_HOME *invisible* for tomcat alone? Am I going to need JRE_HOME anywhere else?

Comment: Turns out, I dont need jre1.8 when I have jdk-11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I tried deleting the JRE_HOME variable and that solved the error.
>   Is this the right method to solve the issue?

Yes. Based on your information , your web app requires Java version >8 to run. And what you do here is to ensure that Tomcat is using Java 11 to run which is the right direction to solve the problem.

Also , it is very normal that you only set `JAVA_HOME` but not set `JRE_HOME` because behind the scenes if you do not set `JRE_HOME` , Tomcat startup script (`setclasspath.bat`) will automatically set `JRE_HOME` for you based on the `JAVA_HOME` value.

You can also customize / override `JRE_HOME` or `JAVA_HOME` by creating a `setenv.sh` inside `bin` folder. All settings inside `setenv.sh` is only applied for the Tomcat  :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk-11.0.2
```

Comment: Is JRE_HOME needed by any other application, services etc? I am curious if deleting JRE_HOME will give errors in future, in some other places, not necessarily with tomcat.

Comment: Not sure , you have to check the services in your server . But you can define JRE_HOME / JAVA_HOME in bin 's setenv.sh which the setting is only applied to the tomcat only. see my update